# Dynamically updating a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

How do I dynamically update a JFrame and replace it with another JFrame without seeing the action visually,
I usually use [this.dispose] to close the current window and call a new JFrame.
Is there a better way to go about the problem.?

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a new JFrame.

Instead you update the components on the current frame. One common way to do this is to use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).